# Robomongo, how to use custom functions?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to use the mongodb client "Robomongo" http://robomongo.org/

It works fine, but I can't understand how to access to the functions created on the "functions" section...

I want to test the mapReduce functionality, so I've created a map() and reduce() function, but when I write on my shell:

```
db.<name_of_collection>.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: {inline: 1}});
```

Robomongo give to me the following error:

```
ReferenceError: map is not defined (shell):1
```

---

I've also tried like this:

```
db.<collection_name>.mapReduce(db.system.js.map, db.system.js.reduce, {out: {inline: 1}});
```

But again, something seems to be wrong...

```
uncaught exception: map reduce failed:{
    "errmsg" : "exception: JavaScript execution failed: ReferenceError: learn is not defined",
    "code" : 16722,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can access stored functions in several ways:

**1)**

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
    "function() { return map(); }", 
    "function(key, values) { return reduce(key, values); }",
    {out: {inline: 1}});
```

**2)**

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() { return map(); }, 
    function(key, values) { return reduce(key, values); },
    {out: {inline: 1}});
```

Note that we are using functions now, not strings as in 1)

**3)**

If you are using MongoDB 2.1 or above, you can do:

```
db.loadServerScripts();
db.collection.mapReduce(
    map, 
    reduce,
    {out: {inline: 1}});
```

More about this:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/

Robomongo use the same engine that is used by MongoDB shell. Your questions is about MongoDB, not Robomongo.

Answer (score 10):

After creating a function using `RoboMongo`,
in the shell command textbox enter:

```
db.loadServerScripts();
myFunctionName();
```

and click `Execute` button in the toolbar